# How can I retrieve JSON stored procedure's result with Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core-2.1

Ciao,
I'm working on a Web API Core 2 project and I'm using Entity Framework Core 2 with a SQL Azure Database.

**Actually**

Inside SQL Azure Database I've a stored procedure that returns a JSON, as you can see below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Procedura]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        dbo.Entity
    FOR JSON AUTO)

    select 0 as 'Id', @data as 'data'
END
```

Actually, to read the result, I had to create a entity that maps the result and reading the data with following code:

```
string json = myContext
    .JsonResult.FromSql("exec dop.sp_Procedura")
    .ToList().FirstOrDefault().data;
```

below the entity class:

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string data { get; set; }
}
```

**Desired**

I think that this solution is not completely clean. My stored procedure should be like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Procedura]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        dbo.Entity
    FOR JSON AUTO
END
```

Having a stored procedure as previous, using EF Core 2.0 Is there a way for read the JSON result like the following pseudo-code?

```
string json = myContext.FromSql("exec dbo.sp_Procedura").Result;
```

Thanks you

Comment: You don't need EF to return a single string. Dapper is a better option here.

Comment: Why do you want to generate JSON on the server anyway? It's easier to do so on the client using JSON.NET. You'd need `FOR JSON` only if you have a complex query that would require querying multiple tables and constructing a complex graph on the client side

Comment: Ciao, @PanagiotisKanavos I agree with you but for an internal policy I cannot use Dapper. About your second comment I've simplyfied the scenario, I need use FOR JSON because my stored procedure build a graph of my entities.

Comment: If you can't use Dapper use a plain old SqlCommand using the DbContext's connection.

Comment: I like this solutions, I didn't know this possibilities. I will try.

Comment: You should probably [show this](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325) to whoever created that policy: `some notable sub-components will be removed from the ASP.NET Core shared framework ... Entity Framework Core`. Later `Entity Framework Core will ship as “pure” NuGet packages in 3.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508073/8254911

Answer (score 1):

With newtonsoft.JSon nuget package, you can convert the Entity to JSON and back. Do not need to implement the stored procedure.

In this way is faster, because the entity framework can use the binary transfer to transfer data from SqlServer and not the whole string content.

here are some samples to json serialize:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

By the way, I believe the SqlServer is also uses the newtonsoft.json inside.

Comment: That's not always the case. The object graph needed to create the same result as `FOR JSON` can be larger and more complex than simply executing a query with `FOR JSON`. `FOR JSON AUTO` wll generate nested objects from JOINs containing just the selected fields from each table. With EF one would have to use a query that returns results in the same shape as the desired JSON file, or have to convert those results to the final form.

Comment: And no, SQL Server doesn't use Json.Net.

Comment: can you give me authentic link for it?  All Microsoft product (Including AzureBlob,CosmosDb ) is use newtonsoft.json. And this package is the official json supportet package by microsft

Comment: [Not quite](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90). Note what JNK himself has to say on this. Just because *some* products and some *clients* in *some* divisions of a company use a package doesn't mean all of them do so.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the db connection directly with SqlCommand for this, ie:

```
var entities = myContext.JsonQuery<List<Entity>>("sp_Procedure");
```

with this extension method:

```
public static T JsonQuery<T>(this DbContext context, string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    using (var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection())
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        connection.Open();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((string)command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```