# entity framework core stored procedure json

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-core-2.0

I have a stored procedure with return json with ... FOR JSON PATH.

How could I run it from entity framework core? 
I can't use FromSql because stored procedure not return entity, so I can't use any Set.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508073/8254911